# Scrollview scrolls up-and-over other content when scrolling

Tags: scrollview, xamarin.forms

When layin out this form, I want a header the size of its content, footer the size of the content, and a middle that expands to take up the rest.  Easy in XAML/UWP.  But in Xamarin Forms when the ScrollView content has data it floats and overlays the top and bottom.  Also when I drag/scroll the ScrollView it can go to the top of the screen.  How to dock the scrollview properly so I have a scrolling middle region?  Thx...

Pictures and XAML layout below....

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="BaseProject.MainPage">
<Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<TableView Grid.Row="0" Intent="Settings" BackgroundColor="Blue" HeightRequest="150" >
  <TableSection Title="Search">
    <ViewCell>
      <Button x:Name="Button_Search" Text="Go"/>
    </ViewCell>
    <EntryCell x:Name="Entry_Cell_SearchFor" />
  </TableSection>
</TableView>
<ScrollView Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
  <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red" >
    <Label Text="body" x:Name="Label_Body" BackgroundColor="Yellow" />
  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
  <StackLayout Grid.Row="2">
    <Label Text="footer"/>
  </StackLayout>
  </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I tried your sample xaml and it behaved as expected. What are you using for the ScrollView content in your real app? I just added a bunch more Labels to the StackLayout inside of the ScrollView to force it to overflow, and it does not escape the boundaries of the central "body" region.

Comment: I was running old xam forms.  I upgraded to the latests, and it works good now.  Thanks Keith, if you want to post an answer I'll tag it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `IsClippedToBounds` property as `true` of `ScrollView`